# In-App Version Checking - Android-Query

Tags: android, android-query

I am using **In-App Version Checking**, and I would like to test the dialog if it's working.

If I try:

*ms.locale(Locale.getDefault().toString()).force(true).level(MarketService.MINOR).checkVersion();*

it works great, but this is a force alert dialog, what I want to use is the automatic code:

*ms.level(MarketService.MINOR).checkVersion();*

but I can't see if it's working.

I tried to low the app versionCode and versionName in the manifest, but it doesn't seems to work.

Any ideas??

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ms.level(MarketService.MAJOR).level(MarketService.MINOR).level(MarketService.REVISION).checkVersion();
```

When you submitting your app, under "What's new in this version?", make sure you open your sentencce with e.g "v1.1.2 ".

Comment: ...is there any issue if I use force to show the alert cause I did that on my app...